# Django: ForeignKey to_field and db_column doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I'm trying to get the field value for `select` widget using `to_field` or `db_column` arguments, but they doesn't seem to work.

Here is the model:

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    e_name     = models.CharField(
                                  max_length = 40, 
                                  verbose_name = 'Name')

    e_lastname = models.CharField(
                                  max_length = 40, 
                                  verbose_name = 'Lastname')

    e_position = models.ForeignKey(
                                   to = Position,  
                                   db_field = 'p_name', # this is the thing I want to display as a select widget option
                                   verbose_name = 'Position')
```

Instead I've only the models' names in select widget, also `db_column` make reference to the `Employer` model, but `Position` reference.

What is going wrong or new features I don't know about?

Sultan

Comment: I don't quite understand, do you mean that you want a form to be able to enter data for this model?

Comment: I want to be able to select position for each newly created `Employer` entity, there are the list of job positions at `Positions` available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is all available **Position**'s to choose from in a html select widget, you can get those like this:

```
p_names = (p.name for p in Position.objects.all())
```

But how do you generate the html? If you are using forms.Form you can use

```
POS_CHOICES = [(p.id, p.name) for p in Position.objects.all()]
class EmployerForm(forms.Form):
    p_choices = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=POS_CHOICES))
```

and render it with in html template:

```
{{form.p_choices}}
```

Have a look at the [forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and [modelforms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Edit:
I just saw the django-admin tag. I don't really know how to do it in the admin area, sorry.

Comment: You could use the ModelChoiceField, so p_choices = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Position.objects.all())

Comment: Looks good. You can even customize what an entry is rendered like in an objects's str method or by overriding the ModelChoiceField's *label_from_instance* method.